# Find Jordan Form of αA (α is a scalar, A a matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

In my linear algebra course I have a problem which goes as follows:

*Suppose A is an nxn matrix over field (R) And J(A) is the jordan form of A.*

*Given **α** belongs to field R, what is the jordan form of **α**A?*

I have worked out, through trial and error, that the jordan form of αA is simply J(A) with the elements (the different eigenvalues) along the diagonal multiplied by **α**.

I couldnt think of a formal proof for this problem, I think it might be some simple characteristic I may have overlooked.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$P^{-1}(\alpha A)P=\alpha P^{-1}AP=\alpha J(A)$ which is similar to a Jordan matrix which is the same as $J(A)$ but the eigenvalues multiplied by $\alpha$.

---

ok GitGud, take a matrix with $\lambda$ on the diagonal and $\alpha$ on the super diagonal, say the matrix is $J$. Then $P=$Dg$[1,1/\alpha,1/\alpha^2,1/\alpha^3,\ldots]$ is a matrix such that $P^{-1}JP$ is in Jordan form. I hope this is sufficient information for you to continue the proof...(referring to the OP)

Comment: You skipped the relevant part.

Comment: If I were to multiply P^(−1)AP by *a* wouldnt I then also multiply the ones in the super diagonal?
Then the matrix would no longer be in Jordan form...

Comment: correct, hence the additional statement: "which is similar to..." and the section under the line...so you have to prove that the alphas in the super-diagonal can be transformed through a similarity transformation to ones

Comment: ok I understand. Thanks!

Comment: I realize that I said I understood, but I am still having problems....
I honestly do understand what you said, about  _P=Dg[1,1/α,1/α2,1/α3,…]_, I tried it out in a small 4x4 matrix and saw that it worked. 
But I obviously cant just write "there exists P so that P=Dg[1,1/α,1/α2,1/α3,]" like you said without showing how I arrived at that conclusion. Not to mention I really want to understand thisI've been thinking about this for a couple of days and I still cant think of the similarity transformation you referenced, so I'd appreciate it if you could help me further. Thanks @Christiaan Hattingh

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh (I used a space in the previous message)
Thank you, once again

Comment: Hi Tom. You can do this proof by induction...analyze first why it works: do the multiplication $P^{-1}J$ - what happens to the $\alpha$ entries in the super diagonal...it should be instantly apparent then why completing the multiplication $P^{-1}JP$ will reduce those entries to ones. So in the induction proof, you can prove that it works for an initial step; it is obvious for $1 \times 1$ - so maybe just also do it for a general $2 \times 2$. Then you must just prove it for the induction step assuming the induction hypothesis...you will learn best if you figure the details out for yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are given $J(A)$, Jordan form of $A$, then there must exist an invertible $P$ such that:

$$P^{-1}AP = J(A)$$

where $J(A)$ is a Jordan Matrix and thus is composed of smaller Jordan blocks, $J(x)$ for each eigenvalue, $x$, of A.

For each block in $J(x)$ of size $n \times n$, where $x$ is a eigenvalue, $P$ will have $n$ columns which are 'responsible'  for the block $J(x)$ in $J(A)$.

We can then take each $i$'th column for    $1 \le i le n$    and multpiply it by   $α^{i-1}$.

Do this for each Jordan block in $J(A)$ and you will obtain the desired $P$ for
$J(αA) = P^{-1}(αA)P$.